# Using services to run code in the background

Tags: java, android, service, background-process

I know this is asked in a lot of questions, and there's a lot of information about it. However I have yet to find an example or complete explanation, on how to just set up a service and run some code in it whilst your Apps running.

Specifically I want to run this code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SearchingFilesMain {


public static void main(String[] arg) {

    String[] array = new String[1000];
    int checker4 = 0;
    String checker3 = "";
    String checker2 = "";
    String checker1 = "";
    String checker = "";
    int num = 0;

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\asciiTracks.txt")));

        while (checker != null) {

            String pattern = "Array Start";
            checker = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0);

            if(checker.equals("Array Start")){

                String pattern2 = "Array Size";
                checker3 = scan.findWithinHorizon(pattern2, 300);

                if(checker3 != null && checker3.equals("Array Size")){                      

                    checker4 = Integer.parseInt(scan.findInLine("(10000|\\d{1,4})"));
                    System.out.println(checker4);
                    checker1 = scan.findWithinHorizon("DATA ASCII", 500);

                    if(checker1 != null && checker1.equals("DATA ASCII")){
                        scan.nextLine();
                        for(int counter = 0; counter<checker4; counter++){

                            array[num] = scan.nextLine();
                            num++;

                            if(num >999){
                                num = 0;
                            }else{}

                        }

                        for(int counter1 = 0 ; counter1 < 1000 ; counter1++){

                            if(array[counter1] != null){
                            System.out.println(array[counter1]);
                            String values = (array[counter1]).toString();
                            System.out.println(values);
                            String[] valueArray = values.split("\\s+");
                            //no value stored in valueArray[0] index for some reason.
                            System.out.println(valueArray[1]);
                            System.out.println(valueArray[2]);
                            System.out.println(valueArray[3]);
                            System.out.println(valueArray[4]);
                            }else{
                                break;
                                }
                        }

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("DATA ASCII not found");
                    }



                }else{System.out.println("no array size");
                //similar code to that above must go in here at a later point.
                //added similar code so far works perfectly at searching through file! 

                 checker1 = scan.findWithinHorizon("DATA ASCII", 500);

                    if(checker1 != null && checker1.equals("DATA ASCII")){
                        scan.nextLine();
                        for(int counter = 0; counter<checker4; counter++){

                            array[num] = scan.nextLine();
                            num++;

                            if(num >999){
                                num = 0;
                            }else{}

                        }

                        for(int counter1 = 0 ; counter1 < 1000 ; counter1++){

                        if(array[counter1] != null){
                        System.out.println(array[counter1]);
                        String values = (array[counter1]).toString();
                        System.out.println(values);
                        String[] valueArray = values.split("\\s+");
                        //no value stored in valueArray[0] for some reason.
                        System.out.println(valueArray[1]);
                        System.out.println(valueArray[2]);
                        System.out.println(valueArray[3]);
                        System.out.println(valueArray[4]);
                        }else{
                            break;
                            }
                        }

                    }else{
                        System.out.println("DATA ASCII not found");
                    }

                }
    }else{System.out.println("no array start");}}}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}}}
```

This code searches through a file looking for keywords and numbers, finding the data related to them and storing it in Arrays. I simply want to run this code in a service in the background alongside my App. I want it to send data back to my App, and update the UI (therefore i believe i need to use a bindservice() ) and start and stop when my App starts and stops.

I want it to be left running the entire time, as at some point it will be reading in data from a network socket.

Any example code you think might work and a small explanation on why it works, or an url to a very simplistic tutorial with example code would be great. Services are completely new to me so if there's a better way of doing what Ive described please feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very good example, but I believe you already read it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

If you want the service to run all the time, you should start it with startForeground, this will tell the OS to not kill it if it runs out of memory. Also you should keep in mind that the Activity may be destroyed while the service is running. If you send data from the Service, make the activity signal the Service when it is destroyed so the service won't crash trying to send info to an nonexistent Activity.

If you have the sdk, you can find some code samples in sdk\samples\android-15\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\

Search for service and you should find an example, start from there and build on top.